# plugin activation in ckeditor

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

i have downloaded the colorbutton plugin. and put the plugin into ckditor plugin folder. in config.js i have activate my plugin . but when i put the activation code in confiq.js file the whole ckeditor is disapper from the page. when i remove this "config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';" from the code ckeditor appear when isert it disapper and i need the text coloroption in ckeditor.

the follwing is the config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

// Define changes to default configuration here.
// For the complete reference:
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];

// Remove some buttons, provided by the standard plugins, which we don't
// need to have in the Standard(s) toolbar.
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

// Se the most common block elements.
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
// Make dialogs simpler.
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
```

var path12=CKEDITOR.basePath;
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = path12+ 'image/browse.php?type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = path12+'image/browse.php?type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = path12+'image/browse.php?type=flash';
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = path12+'image/upload.php?type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = path12+'image/upload.php?type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = path12+'image/upload.php?type=flash';
  config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume you do not have the correct folder structure. Did you place the plugin in the correct folder and its contents?

[plugin_sdk_sample_1](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1)