# CKEditor Plugin Causes Editor to be Hidden

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I'm attempting to use CKeditor on a website, and I need to be able to click to go to links within the editor itself. As this is not possible with the stock editor, I attempted to install the plugin at the following link: https://github.com/mlewand/ckeditor-plugin-openlink

Having downloaded the plugin and tried to install it, when I activate the plugin in config.js the editor on the site page now has the attribute style="visibility:hidden", and when I manually change this to visible via the browser debugger, it shows a default texture rather than the CKeditor editor. It's possible my method of installation of the plugin is to blame, as I'm finding no other instances of people having this issue. The download of the plugin contains a folder "icons" and a folder "lang", as well as plugin.js (the plugin file itself) and a readme.

To install, I simply pasted the relevant contents of the lang files into their respective counterparts in the main CKeditor fileset, and for the time being I ignored the icons folder, as it simply contains the image file for the tool icon; I also commented out the code which calls for this image so as not to have conflict. I then moved plugin.js into the plugins folder within the CKeditor fileset, within its own subfolder plugin as with the stock plugins already present. I then added the lines in the config called for by the readme. I finally added to the config 
`config.extraPlugins = 'plugin';` to enable the plugin. Once I updated all files on the server, it became clear that activating the plugin caused the editor to disappear as I mentioned. If anyone knows why this might be or what I may have done to interfere with the files incorrectly, I'd greatly appreciate it. Currently I'm unsure as to what I could have done better during installation. I can elaborate further if I've been at all unclear. Thank you.

I'll add that here([plugin activation in ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782692/plugin-activation-in-ckeditor)) appears to be a similar issue, although the answer given and the specific issue don't quite seem to apply. If they do, feel free to mark this as a duplicate and I apologize for the redundancy.

EDIT: It appears that the reference added in config.js and the plugin folder name needed to correspond to the name in plugin.js, as I've now discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Important to note that plugin name in plugin.js, name of plugin folder, and reference in config.js must all correspond.